# create file in php with correct encoding for name

Tags: php

I create a file with the instruction $file = fopen($path, 'x+'); the problem is that $path contains caracters that needs utf-8 encoding, the created file appers with name containing characters like this lÃ©la. I dont have a problem writing and reading from the file with 
utf-8.  I have set the utf-8 encoding everywhere ( in apache configuration file httpd.conf, in the php file php.ini) and I have added the utf-8 header, but the problem is still remaining

Comment: what OS are you on? your OS's filesystem may use an encoding != utf8

Answer (score 0):

It means, that your `$path` variable has characters, that are interpreted as lÃ©la in utf-8.
You may use `iconv` function to convert it to correct encoding.